# How to present different Image on Mac Catalyst Version than on iPad Version?

Tags: swift, macos, image, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I created an `iOS App` using `SwiftUI` and enabled used `Mac Catalyst` to port the App on the `Mac`. I used the `Scale Interface to Match iPad` Setting for this.

> Since both Apps have slightly different `App Icons`, I also need to use a different `Image` when displaying the `App Icon` inside the App.

I created an `ImageSet` called `app-icon` and added the `Mac` as a Device. Then I imported the different `App Icon Images` into the different `Device Groups`.

[image: Devices Setting Image Set]

**Problem:** Even though I added the `Mac specific App Icon` into the `Mac Area` of the ImageSet, the Mac App still displays the default iOS one. *How can I fix this Problem?*